# Hide app title on support.v7.widget.toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm starting to develop a new app and I'm triying to give it a material design look. For this, I'm using the v7 support compatibility.

In some activities of the app, I need the toolbar not to show the app title that, I don't know how, but it is showing by default. In those activities, I have a textview at the right side of the toolbar that acts like a button, and where I have implemented traex's [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect).

So, basically my question is, how can I hide the app's title from the toolbar? Because even if I do:

```
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

or

```
toolbar.setTitle(null);
```

it continues appearing.

This is my code:

Custom toolbar xml [toolbar_intro.xml]:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        ripple:rv_centered="false"
        app:rv_rippleDuration="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="Next"/>
    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is how I include the toolbar in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_intro" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro_wellcome);

    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
    }

    TextView toolbar_text = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text);
    toolbar_text.setText(R.string.next);

    ...

}
```

Also, this is the style that I have implemented:

```
<style name="MaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Make sure you check for nullpointer to avoid the warning :)

Comment: you can try as toolbar.setTitle("");

Answer (score 2):

Use

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Under `setContentView()` and  `setSupportActionBar()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.